# Calcular el valor máximo diario de un contaminante y de una estación meteorológica en el programa RStudio o R Commander

Tags: rstudio

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo 3 columnas, una de Fecha, otra de nombres de estaciones (5 en total) y otra de un contaminante con valores numéricos. En total hay 43.000 valores

Se pide calcular el valor máximo diario del contaminante teniendo en cuenta el nombre de la estación.

He intentado hacerlo con el código:

```
Max_PM10_Estaciones_aire_Av_Constitucion<-filter(Estaciones_aire,Estaciones_aire$Nombre==’Estacion Avenida Constitucion’) %>%
group_by(Fecha=Max_PM10_Estaciones_aire_Av_Constitucion$Fecha) %>%
summarise(Max_PM10_Estaciones_aire_Av_Constitucion =max(Max_PM10_Estaciones_aire_Av_Constitucion,na.rm =TRUE))
```

Y me sale el siguiente error:

> Error in group_by(): ! Problem adding computed columns. Caused by
> error in mutate(): ! Problem while computing `Fecha = Max_PM10_Estaciones_aire_Av_Constitucion$Fecha`. Caused by error in
> Max_PM10_Estaciones_aire_Av_Constitucion$Fecha: ! $ operator is
> invalid for atomic vectors Run rlang::last_error() to see where the
> error occurred.

Muchas gracias

Saludos

Rubén